# How does github's page load progress bar work?

Tags: javascript, user-experience

I just noticed github added a progress bar on the top of the page when the page loads. How does this work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Single-page application loading content through AJAX, listening to [`progress` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) on the `xhr` and setting the progress bar's appearance accordingly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Are they using any specific framework for that or is it just their own unique implementation?

Comment: @LightFlow: I wasn't looking at what they did, but suggesting a way to do it.